# how to get a list of all stock symbols from yql

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

since required key is mandatory while executing queries...cant figure out how to do this..

query : select * from yahoo.finance.quotes

Cannot find required keys in where clause; expecting required keys: (symbol)